# Notification and PHP+MySQL design

Tags: php, mysql, notifications

I'm making a website that have posts and replies system.

I'd like to do is when someone replies, sending notification to those who have ever replied (or involved) the post.

My thought is to create a table named `Notification`, contains `message` and `seen` (seen/unread) field. Once people replied, INSERT record to the `Notification` table.

It's seems easy and intuitive, but if there are lots of people involved in, for example, the 31st user replies, 30 people who have ever replied will receive notification. This will make 30 rows of SQL records. And the 32nd user will make 31 records. Then total number of rows will become `30+31=61`.

My question is

1. Is that a good way to handle notification system?
2. If so, how to deal with the duplicate notification (haven't seen but has new reply)
3. As above, will this make a huge server load?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was creating similar system. Here is my experience:

1. My notification table looks like: id (int) | user_id (int) | post_id (int) | last_visited (datetime).
2. user_id + post_id is an [unique](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html) [composite index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-column-indexes.html).
3. So when a user opens the page, I'm looking for an entry (user_id + post_id) in the database. If I find it, then I update the last_visited field if I don't find, then create new row.
4. When I need list messages for notification I'm just query all messages that was created after last_visited time.
5. Also I have cron sript that clean notification for closed posts or banned users.

As for your questions:

1 and 2: You have to find a balance between the amount of data that will be stored and site performance. If you don't need to store all this data you can follow my way. If this data is needed your way is better.

3: It depends on the number of visitors and other functionality. But here is some advices. You must use indexes for MySql table for better perfomance. Also you should think about cron script that will remove useless notifications. If you have huge amount of visitors more than 700k per day you shoulf think about [MogoDb](https://www.mongodb.com/) or other high perfomance [noSql](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL) database.

Comment: I solved my problem by your way. Thank you for your great idea. :)