# How to run mysql query backward?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

The title of question may sound weird but with my english could not get better title.

A have created chat aplication in my website. Now I want to add notifications.

When submitting a new message I am checking if other user has read previous message in given conversation. If he has then I write a new notification. If he has not seen previous then I do not write a new notification.

I use mysql count() function to count fields and then do the php logic. In CI it looks like this:

```
public function ifUnreadMsgs($con_id, $sender_id)
{
    $this->db->where('conversation_id', $con_id);
    $this->db->where('sender_id', $sender_id);
    $this->db->where('seen IS NULL', null, false);
    $this->db->from('messages');
    $count = $this->db->count_all_results();

    if($count > 0){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

My question is about optimization. I do know that with time I will have a lot of messages. Lets say I have 1 000 000 messages stored in database. I also know that the one with possible "NULL" in seen will be with msg_id of approx. 999 995. I have to use this query often and user waits for ajax response so I want to reduce the time for query as much as possible.

Is it possible to run query backward and stop as I hit the value I was looking for? I thought about using DISTICT or LIMIT keyword for stopping but how to run it backwards?

**EDIT:**

Actually I need to start looping through messages table starting from last row, stop at "conversation_id" and look if "seen" is NULL or not.

Comment: Are you just looking for the `ORDER BY` keyword in SQL?  You can change the sort order of your results and then limit the results, effectively giving you the "last matching records" for your query.

Comment: LIMIT is what you want to use, you could also reduce the strain by only SELECTing certain columns.  Then just `return ($count > 0);`.

Comment: I think that my question rises from lack of knowledge of how mysql performs queries. Does ORDER BY starts going through table from last row up to first or does it start from first up to last and then sorts results? I am looking for the first one - to start from last, move upwards and stop on maching condition. I dont want to loop through first 999 990 rows because I already know that I dont need them

Comment: I've asked similar question about that. How about using `last seen` to compare?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37739887/notification-and-phpmysql-design

Answer (score 0):

you can use ORDER BY for both ascending & descending order. by default ORDER BY starts from the first, but you can start it by adding DESC. Please check [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/order-by-optimization.html) & [that](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#ordering-results)